# Is $\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{n}\ge 4$?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction

> Is $$\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{n}\ge 4$$ for natural $n$?

*My Attempt:* Yes. The proof is by induction. Let $f$ be given by $f(n)=\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{n}$. We have $f(1)=\frac{3+1}{1}=4\ge 4$. Assume that $f(r)\ge 4$ for some $r\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $f$ is an increasing function on $\Bbb N$ (since the increase in the exponentiation of $3$, plus or minus one, is greater than that of $n$). Thus $f(r+1)\ge f(r)\ge 4$. $\square$

I'm a bit iffy about the increasing part.

Comment: Use $3^n-(-1)^n \geq 3^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, it will make the induction easy, then check the remaining cases

Comment: Are you asking for `proof-verification` or just a proof?

Comment: Either would be fine, @Jack, although a proof verification would be preferable; see the current tags.

Comment: "Clearly f is an increasing function on N (since the increase in the exponentiation of 3, plus or minus one, is greater than that of n)"  Prove this explicitly.  Why should I believe the exponentiation of $3$ plus or minus $1$ is greater than $n$?  To my mind this is *precisely* what you are being asked to prove.

Comment: Rule of thumb:  Every time you say "clearly" imagine a fiver year old asking "why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exponential functions grow much much faster than polynomials](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf). It is true that for sufficiently large real number $x>0$, 
$$
3^x-1\geq 4x\tag{#}
$$
In fact, one can show that (#) is true for all $x\geq 2$.<sup>(1)</sup> In particular, (#) is true for all positive integer $n\geq 2$. Note that (#) is *stronger* than your inequality.

Now, you only need to check your inequality when $n=1$.

---

(1) To see why this is true, let
$$
f(x)=3^x-1-4x.
$$
Note that $f(2)=0$ and $f'(x)=3^x\cdot \log 3-4\geq 9-4>0$ for $x\geq 2$.

[image]

---

`proof-verification`

> Let $f$ be given by $f(n)=\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{n}$. `(This line is OK.)`
>
> We have $f(1)=\frac{3+1}{1}=4\ge 4$. `(This line is OK.)`
>
> Assume that $f(r)\ge 4$ for some $r\in\Bbb N$. `(This line is OK.)`
>
> Clearly $f$ is an increasing function on $\Bbb N$ (since the increase in the exponentiation of $3$, plus or minus one, is greater than that of $n$ `(Oops, not clear, you need to demonstrate why.)`).
>
> Thus $f(r+1)\ge f(r)\ge 4$. $\square$

Comment: Isn't your method exactly the same as mine?

Comment: @JaideepKhare: I hadn't finished typing my answer (and didn't see yours) while you were posting yours. Mathematically, they are almost the same. I personally prefer using different notations for the function $f$, in this post using $x$ instead of $n$ as the argument, when the sequence is embedded in a function defined on the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{n}\ge 4 \iff3^n-(-1)^n\ge4n$$

thus since

$$3^n-(-1)^n\ge 3^n-1$$

we can prove by induction that  for some $\bar n$ for $n\ge \bar n$ we have

$$3^n-1\ge4n$$

and then verify the cases $n<\bar n$ by direct calculation.

Notably for $3^n-1\ge4n$ we have

- **base case** $n=2\implies 3^2-1=8\ge8$
- **inductive step** let assume $3^n-1\ge4n$ then

$$3^{n+1}-1=3\cdot 3^n-1\ge3(4n+1)-1=12n+2\ge4(n+1)$$

Then $3^n-1\ge4n$ is true for every $n\ge 2$ and thus we need to verify that $3^n-(-1)^n\ge4n$ holds for $n=1$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Since $3^n-(-1)^n>3^n-1$, it's enough to show that $$\frac{3^n-1}{n} \ge 4 \quad n \ge 2$$

(For $n=1$, you've already checked.)

So you need to prove $$f(n)=3^n-1-4n \ge 0 \; \forall n \ge 2 $$

We've $$f'(n) = 3^n \ln 3 -4$$

Now, we've that $f'(2)=9\ln 3-4 >0$ and $f'(n)$ is increasing too, since $3^n$ is increasing.

Therefore, $f(2)=0$ and $f'(n)>0 \; \forall n \ge 2$ proves that $$f(n) >f(2)=0 \implies \frac{3^n-1}{n} \ge 4$$